# I want to flip my screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am adding a flip button in the navigation bar but I don't know the code for flip my screen right to left layout direction. So,please help me with some code or suggestion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OS handles this when the user turns the device. Unless you actually have a view that rotates independently of the device?

Comment: Do you mean flip it upside down, or make it mirror image? And if you mean flip it upside down, do you mean auto-rotate when the user turns the device upside down or do you mean that you want to force it to appear upside down based on the current orientation? (So even if the user turns the device 180 degrees the image stays upside down.)

Comment: What you mean by screen,Do you want view flip animation or viewcontroller flip animation?

Comment: I want viewController flip animation

Comment: @MananChoksi use below solution. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIViewAnimation that flip your screen.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        animations:^{

                     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; //for go back to previous view controller 
                   //otherwise set your view controller if you want go to next screen
                        }
                        completion:NULL];
```

For flip from right set this option **UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight**